# Openc 2.4.6.1 - FaceRecognition - Predicting Several Candidates

Tags: opencv, prediction

I am trying to output several candidates(labels) while doing the prediction using FaceRecognizer class in OpenCv. There is a function FaceRecognizer::predict() which outputs only one choice. What i wanted to have is to get several answers(good candidates) within some threshold/range. I was wondering if it is possible at all?

thanks for reading.

Comment: [this might help](http://answers.opencv.org/question/19681/confidence-values-for-all-faces-from/)

Comment: thanks berak! i will look into it, but seems a bit hard for now ))